# How to mirror statements in Notepad++

Tags: macros, notepad++

I have a file with hundreds of these kind of statements:

- If Description = "Approach light" Then Obstakelcode = "AL"
- If Description = "Common mast" Then Obstakelcode = "CoM"
- etc.

With a Notepad++ macro I tried to 'mirror' these statements in:

- If Obstakelcode = "AL" Then Description = "Approach light"
- If Obstakelcode = "CoM" Then Description = "Common mast"
- etc.

However, I failed. Can anybody tell me if this can be done easily with Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

On the Notepad++ Find/Replace screen, with `Regular expression` selected, please type

Find what

```
If\s(Description\s+=\s+\"[^\"]+\")\s+Then\s(Obstakelcode\s=\s\"[^\"]+\")
```

Replace with

```
If \2 Then \1
```

The expression between `If` and `Then` is captured as group `\1` and the expression between `Then` up to the closing `"` is captured as `\2`. The Replace command mirrors it according to your requirement.